# Encode special characters in javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I defined an ext js column model like this:

```
new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
  defaults: {
    sortable: true
  },
  columns: [
    {id:'msgId',hidden: true, dataIndex: 'msgId'},                  
    {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick = "viewMessage({msgDetails})">View Message Details</a>'} 
  ]
}),
...
..
```

The function call `onClick = "viewMessage({msgDetails})"` fails because msgDetails has got double quotes and special characters which i believe need some kind of encoding before it can be passed around as function argument.
What can be done here?

EDIT: This is the source of msgDetails:

```
var records = Ext.data.Record.create([{name: 'msgId', type:'string', mapping: 'msgId'},
{name: 'msgDetails',type:'string',  mapping: 'msgDetails'}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When msgDetails field is a string, then you should at least quote it:

```
tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick="viewMessage(\'{msgDetails}\')">View Message Details</a>'
```

But instead of writing fragile inline JavaScript you should simply bind a listener to the cellclick event:

```
var infoColumnIndex = 1;
grid.on("cellclick", function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    if (colIndex === infoColumnIndex) {
        viewMessage(grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get("msgDetails"));
    }
});
```

Or take a look at the [ActionColumn](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ActionColumn).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the single and double quotes there. You shouldn't need to encode them to use them as function arguments.

I think the problem is that the following bit is not valid JavaScript:

```
viewMessage({msgDetails})
```

If you have an object literal using { } you have to supply one or more key-value pairs. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but presumably what you really mean is:

```
viewMessage(msgDetails)
// or
viewMessage({msgDetails : 'some details'})
```

If you show where and how you define `msgDetails` I could offer more specific advice.

Comment: Thank you sir. I added the definition of msgDetails to the question

Comment: Hi...can you help me? If I can make the question more clear, please let me know

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with ExtJS, so given that you don't actually have a variable `msgDetails` I think any further advice I try to give might lead you in the wrong direction. It _might_ be something like `viewMessage(records['msgDetails'])`, but that's a guess (I don't know what Ext.data.Record.create does) and I would think you'd need some index value to find the right record.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HTML defined character sets for special characters. For Example

```
&amp;   ampersand &
&lt;    less than sign <
&gt;    greater than sign >
&quot;  the double quote sign "
&#39;   single quote '
```